How To Use the C++ TagLib Library Built with CMake in My Program?
I've just built the C++ TagLib library with CMake using the following commands from within MINGW64:
cd /c/lib
git clone https://github.com/taglib/taglib.git
cd taglib && mkdir build
git submodule update --init (to install the utf8cpp dependency)
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\lib -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
cmake --build .

How do I use this in a program now? Apologies if this question reads lazy. I have no experience with build systems. I read up on CMake the same day I am attempting this install. I saw somewhere I can integrate with Visual Studio 2022, but if possible I'd rather just #include the library using an absolute path if possible. I suppose learning how to integrate with VS wouldn't hurt though. I appreciate any help I can get, thank you.
